# Parallel XML import

Tags: import, parallelization, xml

I need to import some xml information from many pages. I have list of this pages. Doing it in single thread is too long. But I can't access multiple pages from the same IP at the same time. So I need to parallelize program execution with individual proxy settings for each kernel/thread. Is there any way to run several instances of Mathematica with individual proxy settings? It there any other tool to deal with such task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a partial soulution by myself. When I used **ParallelDo** all kernels have the same settings. In **Parallel Kernel Configuration** I create a couple of new kernels. This are **Master Kernels**. Every one of them can have it's own proxy settings. It's possible to assigned different cells to different master kernels.

```
ExpressionCell[Defer[2 * 2], "Input", Evaluator -> "Local"]
```

I would like to know if there is a program way not only assign existing core but to create a new master core.
Finally, I ended up using **curl**. WM created batch file, after it finished, WM processed the data. I did it so, because I can't handle with timeout option of URLFetch/URLRead. This option doesn't seem to work correctly.